# How to find exact opening closing (may be number of closing tags between) tags with content in it and replace in notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, regex

If I'm using regular expression to find exact open and close (even if there is enter mark), it will find only opening and closing tags

regx:
`<del.*?</del>`

But is should find the below exact opening `<del>` to last exact closing `</del>`. (like if we select the one tag it will highlight the exact closing tag)

```
<del cite="FA12-38-5" id="FA12-38-5-d">
<h2 class="l00 r00 t04 b00 c y x">PART 2</h2>
<p class="l01 r00 t01 b00 j z x"><span class="o1">10. </span>Except <del cite="FA01-sched5-328" id="FA01-sched5-328-d">£2.50</del><ins cite="FA01-sched5-328" id="FA01-sched5-328-i">€3.50</ins>, but such dividends shall be assessed and charged under Case III of <a href="sec0018.html" class="i01">Schedule D</a>.</p></del>
```

Comment: "If I'm using regular expression to find exact open and close (even if there is enter mark), it will find only opening and closing tags" - I'm confused what you indeed need. You've nested tags, how do you need to manage them? How many level of nesting you need to consider? Specifying desired output would help. In notepad++ you can check `. matches newline`, that might help.

Comment: You should need to handle nested tags, which unfortunately not managed well in regex. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-balanced-parentheses

Answer (score 1):

There is already an answer for this question on Stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-balanced-parentheses

> Regular expressions are the wrong tool for the job because you are
>   dealing with nested structures, i.e. recursion.
>
> But there is a simple algorithm to do this, which I described in [this
>   answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524548/regular-expression-to-detect-semi-colon-terminated-c-for-while-loops/524624#524624) to a previous question